# Why the compiler points this "Potential null pointer access" warning?

Tags: java, exception, compiler-construction, null

[JDK/JRE 8, Windows 8.1 64-Bit]

So I have a code somewhat like this:

```
File file = ...;
BufferedReader reader = ...;
String s;

while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  s = s.replace("10", "100");

  if (s.startsWith("100100")) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Until there, everything works fine.

But, if I give any condition to execute the `String.replace`, for example:

```
File file = ...;
BufferedReader reader = ...;
String s;

while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  if (file.getName().startsWith("X_")) {
    s = s.replace("10", "100");
  }

  if (s.startsWith("100100")) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then, the compiler gives me a warning `Potential null pointer access: The variable s may be null at this location` at `if (s.startsWith("100100")) {`.

Why this happens?

Comment: Are you sure it's not outside of the `while` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're just encountering a limitation of the static analysis used.  The warning message does say "Potential".  In this case, it's likely because the condition `(s = reader.readLine()) != null` is rather difficult to propagate fully.

Static analyses like these are often heuristics that may not always do exactly what you expect.  They are useful as hint, but they aren't infallible.

You can safely ignore it (provided the code actually works as you intend!), or perhaps add an annotation to suppress that warning.

Comment: I'm fairly certain IDEA correctly handles this case in its own analysis.

Comment: I tested it.  It actually sorta gets it wrong.  If you attempt to use 's' outside the loop, Intelli/J warns that `s` is always null.

Comment: That seems like the correct response, because the loop will run as long as the assignment results in not-null (and end when null is assigned, in which case `s` - immediately after the loop - evaluates to null).

Comment: I expect that the possibly-null heuristic doesn't attempt to traverse while loops, and Intelli/J is indeed fine in this case, although `s` is possibly non-null here.  The warning it produces is that `s` is *always* null

Comment: Oh, well, it is "*always* null [right after the loop, baring no break]" - anyway, I was merely trying to reinforce the statement that this is a limitation with the *particular* static analysis used, which is indeed primitive in javac.